# How can I reuse a python Http connection?

Tags: python, http

The following python script works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import httplib, urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'url':'xxx/xxx/0AAAUw7n6qPQ922.jpg', 'key': 'xxxx'})
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/html"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("xxx.test.com")
conn.request("POST", "/xx/delete", params, headers);
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
print data
conn.close()
```

But if I want to reuse the open http connection to run post more times, it doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import httplib, urllib
import sys

if len(sys.argv)<2:
  print "invalid input"
  sys.exit(0)

path = sys.argv[1]
f = open(path)
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("xxx.test.com")
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/html"}
for line in lines:
  if len(line) < 6:
    continue
  params = urllib.urlencode({'url': line, 'key': 'xxxx'})
  conn.request("POST", "/xx/delete", params, headers);
  response = conn.getresponse()
  print response.status, response.reason
  data = response.read()
  print data
conn.close()
```

The return status is: 500 Server Error

I Just want to reuse the http connection to increase performance, how can I fixed this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dan is it possible apache or the webserver is flushing the connection before the next loop? i know this is very previlant to prevent DDoS of webservers..Might be interesting to see if you are getting a reset packet in there somehow and there for need to open everytime..

Comment: haha, I know how to fix it. Just remove the new line character ('\n') in the string. It works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the newline character ('\n') in the string. It works fine!